# C++: making custom class to work like both container and normal class?

Tags: c++, class, stl

I want to have some `myObject` which will store a collection (vector-like) of `SomeOtherObjects` (so, being homogeneous, right?), which should be iterable and accessible via `(myObject[i]).SomeOtherObjectField1` but also will have normal members like `myObject.doStuff()` and `myObject.Stuff`.

Is there any option to implement such class, or using private std::vector to keep the objects (which I'm trying to avoid - don't like private std:: containers) will be smarter?

Comment: "don't like private std:: containers"  Why not?

Answer (score 1):

Prefer composition over inheritance, if your goal is code reuse.  (Inheritance should be used to enable polymorphism, which doesn't seem to be an issue in this case.)

Answer (score 1):

That's looks like the [composite design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern). In short, you have to define the interface of your `Object` class and derive concrete classes, some being container for others. As said, the composition way is better, but using a common interface is the way to use a 'simple' Object or a 'composite' Object the same way.

my2c

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `private std::vector<>` and an inline method to return a const reference to it.
Why don't you like member std containers?

Answer (score 0):

Often the right approach to structure lies in clarifying the semantics. You need to ask questions like 
"Is myObject a vector<>?". The answer is probably not. If you then follow the principle that a class does one thing (cohesion), then it follows that syntactic sugar around the vector<> is probably not that good.

It tends to follow that the `vector<>` is a private member. There is no problem with then returning a const reference to it. Returning a non-const reference would break encapulsation - might as well be public data.

If you wish to have:

```
(myObject[i]).SomeOtherObjectMethod1();
```

then that is easy enough to implement through `operator[](unsigned index)`. I suspect if you do want that you are better off being consistent and treating `myObject` as a container in its own right. This means not providing the const ref accessor to the `vector<>` and implementing the specific accessor methods you really require. This will make client code much easier to understand.